# Inject в процесс

Tags: c, dll

сделал inject своей dll в процесс. Такой вопрос, что с этим дальше делать если к примеру мне надо посмотреть значение чего либо у этого процесса? Я так понимаю есть сканнер памяти для процессов где я могу посмотреть адрес указателя/переменной и считать значение или как вообще это происходит? Если есть пример - буду очень признателен.

Comment: В каждом случае свои фишки. Желательно знать, на чем написана программа. Изначально поиск делается вручную, что бы понять структуру классов/структур приложения и найти формулу, которая всегда будет выдавать правильный адрес того, что вы собрались менять.

Comment: Ну я пишу на Си, но да...тут полазил и понял примерный вектор. В конечном итоге надо получить адрес и сделать указатель...если я не ошибаюсь